# r script to loop through two lists, find matches in the first column, then append that line of both lsits together

Tags: r, loops, expression

I have produced a list of differential expressed genes (DE list), containing the gene_ID and FDR values etc for my organism.

I also have a list from biomart of all of the gene_IDs in my organism in the first column, in the third are all the orthologues in from the zebrafish.

I would like to write a loop in R, to find the matching gene_IDs in my DE list that are present in the biomart list, then append a new column on the DE list with the zebrafish orthologue in order to have a master spreadsheet.

can anyone help?

Comment: no loop needed if you can convert your lists to dataframes with `do.call(rbind, list)` You want to look up `?merge` or `?dplyr::full_join` Something like this should get you close once you have dataframes: `dplyr::inner_join(dplyr::select(biomart, 1,3), DE)` you need to make sure the column names match for gene id between your DE and biomart

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly!!